# Android: How to create custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I have to create a custom view to show a little graph on Android. There are a lot of tutorials but they didn't help me. They are full of resource handling, performance optimizations etc.

But I fail at the simplest thing: The view is not visible. Neither in Android Studio, nor in the running app.

Here my approach:

/home/thomas/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/src/main/java/clear/test/MainActivity.java:

```
package clear.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

/home/thomas/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/src/main/java/clear/test/MyView.java:

```
package clear.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xFF0000);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), 0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(500, 500);
    }
}
```

/home/thomas/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <clear.test.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem:
Color is 32 bit. Red must be `0xFFFF0000`, not `0xFF0000`.

Comment: If you solved your own problem then please mark your own answer as the solution.

Comment: And yeah, 0xFF0000 = 0x00FF0000 *is* red, but with zero opacity, rendering it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `wrap_content` for your view but do not implement the measure functions

Answer (score 0):

1) Your view is "visible" but its height and width is 0 because of `wrap_content` in `activity_main.xml`. Try to set some absolute values or `match_parent`.

2) Do **NOT** create new instances of `Paint` in every call of `onDraw`. It`s useless.

3) If you want to define custom view both by java and xml (or I don't understand existence of file `sample_my_view.xml`), look for `View`'s method `inflate()`.

Comment: I added the onMeasure-method. Now I can see the size of the view, but no rendering. sample_my_view.xml was created by Android Studio. I deleted it.